# Javascript .clone change inner class

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, clone, addclass

I am currently developing a SharePoint App in Visual Studio 2013 and I have some code that clones a table I have, however when I have cloned the table I need to change the class of a specific table row. The reason for this is that the specific table row is hidden until a tick box is selected.

My current code looks like the following:

```
function repeatingSection() {
    $('#repeatingBtn').click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var lastRepeatingGroup = $('.Section').last();
        var cloned = lastRepeatingGroup.clone(true);
        cloned.insertAfter(lastRepeatingGroup);
        cloned.find("input").val("");
    });
}
```

I have tried using the below code:

```
  var cloned = lastRepeatingGroup.clone(true).attr('id', id += $('.newClass').length).addClass('newClass');
```

however I found that this only added the class the table that was being cloned, however I need a specific table row to have a different class or id, my html looks like the following:

```
<table class="Section">
    <tr id="NoneHiddenFields">
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="LblOne" runat="server" Text="ID"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="InputName" class="InputID_1" readonly="readonly" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="LblTwo" runat="server" Text="Required"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="InputCheckBox" class="InputChexkBox_1" readonly="readonly" />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="HiddenFields" class="HiddenFields_1">
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="LblThree" runat="server" Text="ID"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" id="InputID" class="InputID_1" readonly="readonly" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="LblFour" runat="server" Text="Number"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" id="InputNo" class="InputNo_1" readonly="readonly" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see I need to change the id of the 'hiddenFields' table row class or ID. I understand that everytime I insert a new section i will need to increment a number to the end of the class/ID, however I am struggling to see a way to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: JavaScript can only modify the output HTML, not the server-side ASP. Please share the output HTML instead.

Comment: I don't need to change the ASP though I only need to change the value of the table row <tr> that has an ID assigned to it.